# How to Seal Gaps in Heater/AC Unit Door?

Tags: doors, sealing

[image]

Both the wall and the plywood door are bowed (not straight/level). Any ideas on how to remake the door or seal the gaps? Mainly I am concerned about rodents& mosquitos not looks.

Comment: You could try removing the door, getting it damp, and bending it into proper shape to let dry.  Then don't let it get wet again.  Might work, might not.

Answer (score 0):

A door made of plywood is bound to be a problem.

Your best bet is to get a new door, not made from plywood.

Or if, as you say looks are not important, get a latch to hold the top of the door closed.